# Mongoose.js CastError: Cast to Number failed for value "{ '$gte': 1 }" at path "access" for model "Projekt"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to find a user inside of an array of users who have the same id as the one in my token and access greater than 1.

to do so I'm using the following code but I'm getting a CastError:

```
Project.findOne({ Users: {User: decoded._id, access: { $gte: authStatus }}, _id: id })
        .then((result) => {
            console.log(result)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        });
```

My Schema:

```
const ProjectSchema = new Schema(
{
    Users: [
        {
            User: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'usertemps' },
            access: { type: Number, required: true }
        }
    ],
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    deadline: { type: Date, required: true }
},
{
    timestamps: true
}
);
```

CastError:

```
    CastError: Cast to Number failed for value "{ '$gte': 1 }" at path "access" for model "Projekt"
    at model.Query.exec (C:\Users\tomod\OneDrive\Dokumenter\GitHub\Project-Manager-Project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4371:21)
    at model.Query.Query.then (C:\Users\tomod\OneDrive\Dokumenter\GitHub\Project-Manager-Project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4463:15)
    at validateOwner (C:\Users\tomod\OneDrive\Dokumenter\GitHub\Project-Manager-Project\routes\modules\verifyAccess.js:10:5)
    at C:\Users\tomod\OneDrive\Dokumenter\GitHub\Project-Manager-Project\routes\project.route.js:44:33
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\tomod\OneDrive\Dokumenter\GitHub\Project-Manager-Project\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\tomod\OneDrive\Dokumenter\GitHub\Project-Manager-Project\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\tomod\OneDrive\Dokumenter\GitHub\Project-Manager-Project\routes\modules\verifyToken.js:11:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\tomod\OneDrive\Dokumenter\GitHub\Project-Manager-Project\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\tomod\OneDrive\Dokumenter\GitHub\Project-Manager-Project\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\tomod\OneDrive\Dokumenter\GitHub\Project-Manager-Project\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\tomod\OneDrive\Dokumenter\GitHub\Project-Manager-Project\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\tomod\OneDrive\Dokumenter\GitHub\Project-Manager-Project\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at param (C:\Users\tomod\OneDrive\Dokumenter\GitHub\Project-Manager-Project\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:354:14)
    at param (C:\Users\tomod\OneDrive\Dokumenter\GitHub\Project-Manager-Project\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:365:14)
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\tomod\OneDrive\Dokumenter\GitHub\Project-Manager-Project\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:410:3)
    at next (C:\Users\tomod\OneDrive\Dokumenter\GitHub\Project-Manager-Project\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10) {
  messageFormat: undefined,
  stringValue: `"{ '$gte': 1 }"`,
  kind: 'Number',
  value: { '$gte': 1 },
  path: 'access',
  reason: AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: The expression evaluated to a falsy value:

    assert.ok(!isNaN(val))

      at castNumber (C:\Users\tomod\OneDrive\Dokumenter\GitHub\Project-Manager-Project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\cast\number.js:28:10)
      at SchemaNumber.cast (C:\Users\tomod\OneDrive\Dokumenter\GitHub\Project-Manager-Project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\number.js:382:12)
      at SchemaNumber.SchemaType.applySetters (C:\Users\tomod\OneDrive\Dokumenter\GitHub\Project-Manager-Project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1075:12)
      at EmbeddedDocument.$set (C:\Users\tomod\OneDrive\Dokumenter\GitHub\Project-Manager-Project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1250:20)
      at EmbeddedDocument._handleIndex (C:\Users\tomod\OneDrive\Dokumenter\GitHub\Project-Manager-Project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1019:14)
      at EmbeddedDocument.$set (C:\Users\tomod\OneDrive\Dokumenter\GitHub\Project-Manager-Project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:960:22)
      at EmbeddedDocument.Document (C:\Users\tomod\OneDrive\Dokumenter\GitHub\Project-Manager-Project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:150:12)
      at EmbeddedDocument [as constructor] (C:\Users\tomod\OneDrive\Dokumenter\GitHub\Project-Manager-Project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\types\embedded.js:42:12)
      at new EmbeddedDocument (C:\Users\tomod\OneDrive\Dokumenter\GitHub\Project-Manager-Project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\documentarray.js:115:17)
      at DocumentArrayPath.SchemaArray.castForQuery (C:\Users\tomod\OneDrive\Dokumenter\GitHub\Project-Manager-Project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\array.js:485:13)
      at DocumentArrayPath.SchemaType.castForQueryWrapper (C:\Users\tomod\OneDrive\Dokumenter\GitHub\Project-Manager-Project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1477:20)
      at cast (C:\Users\tomod\OneDrive\Dokumenter\GitHub\Project-Manager-Project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\cast.js:274:34)
      at model.Query.Query.cast (C:\Users\tomod\OneDrive\Dokumenter\GitHub\Project-Manager-Project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4772:12)
      at model.Query.Query._castConditions (C:\Users\tomod\OneDrive\Dokumenter\GitHub\Project-Manager-Project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:1872:10)
      at model.Query.<anonymous> (C:\Users\tomod\OneDrive\Dokumenter\GitHub\Project-Manager-Project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2129:8)
      at model.Query._wrappedThunk [as _findOne] (C:\Users\tomod\OneDrive\Dokumenter\GitHub\Project-Manager-Project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\query\wrapThunk.js:16:8) {
    generatedMessage: true,
    code: 'ERR_ASSERTION',
    actual: false,
    expected: true,
    operator: '=='
  }
}
```

Is it possible to do it this way or am I going about this all wrong?

Hope someone can help thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to query nested fields, you should use the [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/#query-on-nested-field).

```js
Project.findOne({
  "Users.User": decoded._id,
  "Users.access": { $gte: authStatus },
  _id: id,
})
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Edit:

In order to filter the elements inside an array and return only the elements that match certain condition, you can use `$filter` operator

```js
Project.aggregate([
  { $match: { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id) } },
  {
    $project: {
      name: 1,
      deadline: 1,
      Users: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$Users",
          as: "user",
          cond: {
            $and: [
              {
                $eq: ["$$user.User", mongoose.Types.ObjectId(decoded._id)],
              },
              { $gte: ["$$user.access", authStatus] },
            ],
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
])
  .then((result) => {
    // Aggregate method only returns an array, since we are doing a $match based on _id, 
    // we can take the first element in the array if present
    if (result && result.length) {
      console.log(result[0]);
    }
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Comment: I have already tried this and it did not work. The problem is that I have to find a specific user who has the id I'm looking for and a high enough access value. If I use the dot notation it just finds any user with the id and any user with a high enough access value.

Comment: @MartinOlesen Based on my understanding, you only need the `Users` array in the result to have users that match the condition. I have updated the answer based on that. Please check